# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = java.util.ArrayList)

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

Reaching to ask for your help on this one.

I'm getting the error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = java.util.ArrayList)`

I'm already implementing Parcelable both in the Entities class (which is an ArrayList of Entity) as in the Entity class.

The code for the Entities class is as follows:

```
package my.package;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Entities implements Parcelable {
    private ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    public Entities() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(ArrayList<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    // Parcelable
    private Entities(Parcel in) {
        entities = (ArrayList<Entity>) in.readSerializable();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeSerializable(entities);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Entities> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Entities>() {
        @Override
        public Entities createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Entities(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public Entities[] newArray(int i) {
            return new Entities[i];
        }
    };
}
```

And to move into the next Activity I'm doing so:

```
ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
Entities entities_ = new Entities();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_Entities.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject_Entity = jsonArray_Entities.getJSONObject(i);

    Entity entity = new Entity();
    (Here goes all the entity.set() logic)

    entities.add(entity);
}

entities_.setEntities(entities);

if (entities.size() > 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchEntitiesActivity.this, ListEntitiesActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("entities", entities_);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can you identify what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [`writeParcelableList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel?hl=en#writeParcelableList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20int)) instead of `writeSerializable()` (and similarly for read).

Comment: It is the answer. You saved my day, thank you. Do you want to answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ArrayList`, I recommend [`writeParcelableList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#writeParcelableList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20int)) instead of `writeSerializable()`, and [`readArrayList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readArrayList(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)) instead of `readSerializable()`.

Of course, really I recommend Kotlin and `@Parcelize`, where all this stuff gets nicely code-generated for you!